# How does SoundCloud make the favicon dynamically change when the play button is pressed?

Tags: php, javascript, html, favicon, soundcloud

Example: http://soundcloud.com/torsmusic/emancipator-siren-tor-remix

You will notice that if you click play, the favicon dynamically displays a play icon next to its original favicon. What is the method used for this?

Comment: Little unrelated, but if you want to dynamically change favicon when music plays. Have a look at [this](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/) soundManager demo. Inside config, if you do a `useFavIcon : true`, it will show visualization in the favicon. 

[source code](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/generated/demo/page-player/script/page-player.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if you look at the page, it's not changing the favicon, but pre-pending the play button in front of the title. The favicon itself doesn't change.